# Creating varying pre-set comments in a single MS Word VBA script

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently using this very simple script to leave comments on MS Word files:

```
Sub Comment()

ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True
Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="Comment Text"

End Sub
```

I wonder if this script can be upgraded in such a way that it would cycle a set of different comments as I go through the text? I am doing this as I have assigned a comment to almost every keyboard combination as a shortcut --and it is very cumbersome to memorize all those shortcuts.

Comment: When you say 'cycle a set of different comments...', do you mean that a pre-determined range of comments will be placed, for example, in selections 1, 2 and 3 it would be "comment 1", "Comment 2", "Comment 3" and then in selections 4, 5 and 5 the comments would start over from "comment 1" etc.?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant! I am going to try MacroPod's script, now. I hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be as simple as:

```
Sub CommentSelect()
With Selection
  Select Case InputBox("Choose: " & vbCr & _
    "1. Comment 1 Description" & vbCr & _
    "2. Comment 2 Description" & vbCr & _
    "3. Comment 3 Description" & vbCr & _
    "4. Comment 4 Description" & vbCr & _
    "5. Comment 5 Description")
    Case 1: .Comments.Add .Range, "Comment 1 Text"
    Case 2: .Comments.Add .Range, "Comment 2 Text"
    Case 3: .Comments.Add .Range, "Comment 3 Text"
    Case 4: .Comments.Add .Range, "Comment 4 Text"
    Case 5: .Comments.Add .Range, "Comment 5 Text"
  Case Else
End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What I meant was a script that could cycle these comments automatically. However, a script that allow me too choose among given options is even more helpful. Thanks for this! You've been so much helpful!!!